# Is it possible to register with Container without using @Repository or @Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<AccountDBModel, Long> {

  @Modifying
  @Query(value = PortfolioQuery.ACCOUNT_INSERT)
  void insert(@Param("exchangeId") Long exchangeId, @Param("name") String name, @Param("siteAccount") String siteAccount,
      @Param("memo") String memo, @Param("createdAt") Long createdAt, @Param("updatedAt") Long updatedAt,
      @Param("isActive") Boolean isActive);

  @Modifying
  @Query(value = PortfolioQuery.ACCOUNT_UPDATE)
  void update(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("exchangeId") Long exchangeId, @Param("name") String name,
      @Param("siteAccount") String siteAccount, @Param("memo") String memo, @Param("updatedAt") Long updatedAt,
      @Param("isActive") Boolean isActive);

  @Query
  Optional<AccountDBModel> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

```
@Service
public class AccountService {

  private final AccountRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  public AccountService(AccountRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  public void postAccount(AccountBaseModel baseModel) throws Exception {
    Long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.repository.insert(baseModel.getExchangeId(), baseModel.getName(), baseModel.getSiteAccount(),
        baseModel.getMemo(), now, now, baseModel.getIsActive());
  }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
class WaveBackofficeApiApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Test
  public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
    if (applicationContext != null) {
      String[] beans = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();

      for (String bean : beans) {
        System.out.println("bean : " + bean);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: bean : accountRepository]

As you can see in AccountRepository interface I didn't use @Repository in AccountRepository interface.

But why is it registered as a bean in Spring Container?

There are no other class like AppConfig.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created interface called `AccountRepository` and extended (thus **inherited**) `CrudRepository`.

Now just do `Ctrl + Left mouse click` on `CrudRepository`, you will end up in it:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);

    Optional<T> findById(ID id);

    boolean existsById(ID id);

    Iterable<T> findAll();

    Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);

    long count();

    void deleteById(ID id);

    void delete(T entity);

    void deleteAllById(Iterable<? extends ID> ids);

    void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T> entities);

    void deleteAll();
}
```

Intellij actually gives you oportunity to find the implementations of all those methods with arrow down mark on the left side. [image: Look]

So there is a huge class called `SimpleJpaRepository` that has all the implementations, the actual code.

**AND THE THING IS**...

SimpleJpaRepository.class does have `@Repository` in it:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(
    readOnly = true
)
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID> {
```

Comment: Maybe you are a genius. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The interface itself is not registered as a bean. spring framework provides existing implementation of a repository bean (default impl is the class SimpleJpaRepository), which gets injected based on the specifications you provide in your interface. This specific class has the @Repository annotation and will be picked up by spring as a bean.

A simple overview:

```java
@Repository
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID>  {
    // code
}

public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {}


@Service
public MyService() {
    @Autowired private MyRepository myRepository;
}
```

In the example above, our own repository interface extends CrudRepository, which has an implementation class named SimpleJpaRepository (provided in the framework), and SimpleJpaRepository is registered as a bean. In MyService, we just tell that we want a bean of type MyRepository, and Spring will inject an instance of SimpleJpaRepository.

Comment: Then how is accountRepository(Bean) registered?

Comment: @CodingBaby It is registered because it has implementation with "@Repository" marked. Follow my answer, I showed where its implementation is.

Comment: @Vusual that's exactly what i said in the first sentence of my answer...

Comment: Updated answer with repo example if it was unclear with the other example. @CodingBaby the same happens with any class in spring. If you have a class with is registered as a bean, it will be a candidate for being injected anywhere you e.g. autowire an interface that is implemented by the class. So basically, the only thing we do with extending the repository interfaces is that we define what types should be used, as well as if there are any custom queries etc. that we can add with Query Methods, Query annotations, etc.